# JQuery code to focus content inside a scrollpane

Tags: jquery, scroll, focus, scrollbar

I had a search page wherein on the left side I had several options which the user can check.
When the user selects an option on the left, a corresponding content will be displayed on the right side.
The content on the right is inside a div which has a specified height and will have scroll bar when the content increases.

Now the problem is the user could not view directly the content on the right side when there are several contents being displayed. The user must scroll down to see the content.

Is there a way in jquery to show/focus the corresponding content on the right side. Just to avoid the hassle for the user to scroll down.
Somewhat like an anchor within the page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on click of the option write this it will draw to the particular ID with animation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery("#OPTION_ID").click(function (){

      jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#RIGHTSIDE_CONTENT_ID").offset().top }, 1000);
  })
})
```

It will work.... :)

Comment: thanks. I just modify the first selector (html, body) into the div id because it is the page that will scroll down not scrollpane. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for jQuery's [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) method

```
$('#button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.thisContent').focus();
});
```

Comment: what should be html tag for the content? i tried it on a table and link, and it will not scrolldown to focus the content?

Comment: You probably need to prevent the default action if you are clicking. This is done by `e.preventDefault()` or returning false. Look at the modified code.

Comment: Thanks. But I need the click action. since the user will select from list of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

on click of the option write this it will draw to the particular ID with animation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

  jQuery("#OPTION_ID").click(function (){

      jQuery("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#RIGHTSIDE_CONTENT_ID").offset().top }, 1000);   }) })
```

have a doubt in this script, what is it mean 'jQuery("html, body")', html and body point to where?